# como realizar una consulta eloquent a varias collections?

Tags: laravel, mongodb, eloquent, collection

estoy intentando realizar una consulta con eloquent a una coleccion y obetener de forma anidada otra coleccion. Estoy usando laravel 7 y mongodb. El problema esta en que me devuelve la coleccion anidada como un array vacio. en la coleccion anidada necesito traer solo el primero de una lista ordenada de forma descendente (esto lo probé en otra query y funciona bien). Y a su vez, el primero de la coleccion expediente.

```
    $expediente = Expediente::where('expediente', 'EX-2020-xxxxxxxx-xxx-xx#xxxx')
->with(['pases' => function($q) use ($yesterday) {
            $q->where('created_at', ">=" , $yesterday )
            ->orderBy('fecha_salida', 'desc')
            ->first();
        }
        ])->first();`
```

Acá esta mi modelo expediente:

```
 public function pases()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Pase::class);
    }
```

mi modelo pases:

```
public function expediente()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Expediente::class);
    }
```

Obtengo la collecion expediente con el array vacio :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo generas `yesterday`?

Comment: Lo genero con Carbon de laravel. La fecha de ayer convertida a objeto UTCDateTime de mongoDB.

Comment: seria esto: MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime {#358
  +"milliseconds": "1599955200000"
}

Comment: y apuntas a `milliseconds`?

Comment: no es necesario tanta precision pero el dato llega y lo guardo en bd. No tuve problemas por eso lo estoy trabajando asi. Yo necesito desde el dia anterior ej: 2020/09/13 00:00:00 hasta el dia de la fecha todo lo q se haya cargado